# How to check remotely if my .net console app is running by sending a request to it and getting a custom response from it

Tags: c#, .net

In my network I have a c# .net console app running on another windows system. I would like to implement in it a feature to send a request to it and get a custom response from it (for example json).

My goal is to test if the remote console app is alive and works as expected. When my request reaches the console app, it will run a few self tests and its response will contain these self-test-results. I have full control over the source code of the remote console app.

What is the easiest technology / framework to implement my idea in this remote .net console app?

I prefer to have the remote .net console app set up as a simple console.exe, so preferrably no IIS hosted website, no WCF, and no windows service. However, I am open to use any of the aforementioned technologies, if there really is no simpler way than a plain console.exe, and if I have to use one of them, which one is the simpliest?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing that prevents a console application from opening an HTTP endpoint and communicating over it. Specifically, WCF has samples that demonstrate hosting it from a console application, though any other RPC technology of your choice works as well. You're going to need to open *some* kind of endpoint in any case, because the only other lines of communication a console application has are the standard input/output streams, which are not reachable remotely.

Comment: You could host a WCF service in a console app without using IIS. You may also want to take a look at [gRPC](https://grpc.io/). It's a "modern open source high performance RPC framework" create by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a TCP listener running alongside your console application so it is able to respond to queries remotely.

A really good tutorial for using a TCP listener in C# can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C)

Generally on your "server" in this case your console application you can define a tcplistener which will accept requests on a specified port and can communicate back to the client that initiated the connection

(taken from the site linked above)

```
    try {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.5.99");
         // use local m/c IP address, and 
         // use the same in the client

/* Initializes the Listener */
        TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

/* Start Listeneting at the specified port */        
        myList.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
        Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                          myList.LocalEndpoint );
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

        Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

        byte[] b=new byte[100];
        int k=s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
        for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
        Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
/* clean up */            
        s.Close();
        myList.Stop();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
    }    
    }
```

In order to actually see the response from the server you would have to write a complementary client application which will send the request to the console application

again from the site linked above

```
 try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("172.21.5.99",8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str=Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I would repurpose the code above so that instead of sending and replying an arbitrary string, it could instead reply the status of your console application after running the self checks you mentioned.

Hope this helps - James

Comment: I tested your solution and it works perfectly, thanks!! I am checking out the self-hosted ASP.NET WebAPI using Kestrel proposed by @Murven

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it does not require the understanding of a .net or .net core web api and meets more closely my specific need :-)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to implement a [self-hosted ASP.NET WebAPI using Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows).

This would make your application ready for the future and you would not be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree with this.  Re-use Kestrel rather than implementing your own HTTP stack.  It works fine and is less likely to induce an error than writing custom code would be.

Comment: I checked out your suggestion, found this [.net self hosted web api](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092504/Creating-Self-Hosted-ASP-NET-WebAPI-with-CRUD-oper) and this [.net core self hosted web api](https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/18/your-first-net-core-web-application-using-nothing-but-the-command-line), of which I got both working, and agree that your suggestion is more future proof. However I accept @James m answer, because it does not require the understanding of a web api and meets more closely my specific need. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer!! :-)